# jquery scrolltop does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"> </script> 

         <script>   
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

       jQuery('.scrollToTop').click(function(){ 
           $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: ($("#company_info").first().offset().top)
           }, 1200);
      });
    });
 </script> 
    <body>
                  <section class="get_started">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12 relative">
            <h2 id="gs_button"><a href="#company_info"><span>Get<br/> Started</span></a></h2>
        </div>`enter preformatted text here`
    </div>
    </section>
       <a style="display: inline;" href="#" class="scrollToTop">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>

    </body>
the scrolltoTop is working in firefox and this code is not working in chrome.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `id="company_info"` in anchor tag `<a id="company_info href="#">`. Then it will work smoothly.